# How to show that the linear programme is unbounded objective function?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

What is the way I can prove any linear program has an unbounded solution? 
Take for example below, its clear that it has infinitely many solutions. However, I want to know a method which tells systematic way of computing if any linear program has an unbounded solution.

[image: Linear equation example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's work with a linear program in the form you have used for your example, that is, a problem of the form 
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\max & c^Tx \\
\textrm{subject to} & \quad Ax = b\\ 
& x \geq 0
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
You can think of certain vectors $y$ as directions leading to "unboundedness" if they satisfy the following two conditions:

1. $Ay = 0,\, y \geq 0$,
2. $c^Ty > 0$.

The intuition is that any vector $y$ that satisfies condition (1) does not affect feasibility. More concretely, consider any feasible point $x^*$ (which means that $x^* \geq 0$ and $Ax^*=b$). Now consider any number $t > 0$ and the vector obtained by considering the sum $x^* + ty$. Since $x^* \geq 0$, $t > 0$ and $y \geq 0$ it follow that $x^* + ty \geq 0$ (the sum of non-negative quantities is non-negative). Also notice that
$$
A(x^* + ty) = Ax^* + A(ty) = Ax^* + t(Ay) = b + t(0) = b.
$$ 
So it turns out that $x^* + ty$ is a feasible solution for your linear program. Moreover, this holds for any $t > 0$. If you trace out all the values of $(x^* + ty)$ for all $t > 0$ you end up with a ray with base point $x^*$ and direction $y$. Think of this ray as a "half-line" of infinite length in one direction starting at the point $x^*$.

Now let's consider condition (2) which tells you what happens when you scale $y$. Suppose that $c^Ty = v$; condition (2) tells us that $v > 0$. Choose any $t > 1$ and observe that
$$
c^T(t\cdot y) = t \cdot c^Ty = tv > v.
$$
If you look more closely at the steps above you will see that $c^Ty$ keeps increasing **proportionally** as we increase $t$ which means that $c^Ty \to \infty$ as $t \to \infty$.

So a linear program is unbounded if it has a feasible solution (our $x^*$ above) and a vector $y$ that satisfies conditions (1) and (2). This provides a systematic way to show that a linear program is unbounded.

Comment: you have considered only equality constraint, how to handle in equality constraints?

Comment: A common exercise in linear programming is to convert various combinations of constraints into linear programming "standard forms". There are several "tricks" to do this. For example, in this case we could convert $Ax \leq b, \, x \geq 0$ into $Ax + s =b, \, x\geq 0, \, s \geq 0$ by adding the non-negative slack variables $s$. Notice we have converted an inequality case into the equality form described in the solution above by augmenting the matrix $A$ into $[A \mid I]$ and the variable $x$ into $[x; s]$ (vertically stacked).